# How to tell if a craftable item will be an upgrade?

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

If you go to craft an item in Dragon Age Inquisition, you get the following kind of screen:

[image: Armor Crafting screen]

Now I would like to know if the craftable is a potential upgrade. I'm assuming that I can do so somehow, because top-right you have a set of controls to switch to different party members.

However, I can not find a way to see what my selected party member is currently wearing, let alone compare that to the potential item I'm making.

I've tried hovering and right clicking everywhere in the UI, but haven't found an option to do this. Is going back and forth between the Crafting UI and Inventory UI (and remembering or screenshotting in between) really the easiest way to see if something would be an upgrade for a character?

Comment: Maybe I'm misremembering, but I think I always exited the menu and memorized my armor stats. I don't think there is a comparison.

Comment: @Kodama Uh oh... given the lack of other response, I had already started to figure that might be the answer :'(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After just completing my third playthrough of the game, I have not found a way to do this. You will have to switch between the Inventory screen and the Crafting screen to accomplish this. I've spent a lot of time doing exactly that.

---

> I'm assuming that I can do so somehow, because top-right you have a set of controls to switch to different party members.

There is a (minor) reason for the ability to switch party members. When you select a craftable item, the selected party member will be shown wearing this item **only if they can equip it**.

For example, in your image, Iron Bull will be shown in his *current* armor if you select a light/medium recipe. He will be shown wearing the *selected* armor if you select a heavy armor.
Note that the "... of the Dragon" armors are unique to the Inquisitor, and therefore you won't see Iron Bull equip them even if you've selected the heavy "... of the Dragon" armor.